# Need this field to be as originally, number; not string

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In this query, the field UAFLWD, on the IBM I is defined as numeric 8 0. it is actually a date field, YYYYMMDD. This code below changes the format to STRING, called now FOLLOWUP.
Actually I would like this to be NUMBER, because in the reporting tool, i want to include only dates = to the current date and previous. How can i define this FOLLOWUP to be a number?

```
SELECT                                                                              
  ALL       T01.UAUSRN,                                                             
            SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD),5,2) CONCAT '/' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD)      
            ,7,2) CONCAT '/' CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD),3,2) AS FOLLOWUP,         
            (T01.UAENT#), T01.UASFX#, T02.ADENTN, T01.UANOTT, T01.UANOTL,  T02.ADLNM, T02.ADFNM,         
            T01.UAFLWD                                                              
  FROM      ASTDTA.NOTEHDUA T01 INNER JOIN                                            
            ASTDTA.ADRESsad T02                                                       
  ON        UAENT# = ADENT#                                                         
    AND     UASFX# = ADSFX#                                                         
  WHERE     UAFLWD BETWEEN 20000101 AND 20991231                                    
    AND     UAPRGD < 1                                                              
    AND     UANOTT = 'E'                                                            
  ORDER BY  001 ASC, 008 ASC
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the conversion?  Don't you just need to modify the `WHERE` clause?  Thankfully this is a SARGable format, although the type of the column should still be changed if possible.

Comment: question is have is, how to ignore a date like this: 40/12/14 (dd/mm/yy)

Comment: What, you have invalid data in the column?  Then you should clean that up.  Not reporting it is just papering over a (rather dangerous) flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you looking for?  According to your question it's already numeric so just select it without any conversion:

```
SELECT
  ALL       T01.UAUSRN, UAFLWD AS FOLLOWUP,
            (T01.UAENT#), T01.UASFX#, T02.ADENTN, T01.UANOTT, T01.UANOTL,  T02.ADLNM, T02.ADFNM,         
            T01.UAFLWD                                                              
  FROM      ASTDTA.NOTEHDUA T01 INNER JOIN                                            
            ASTDTA.ADRESsad T02                                                       
  ON        UAENT# = ADENT#                                                         
    AND     UASFX# = ADSFX#                                                         
  WHERE     UAFLWD BETWEEN 20000101 AND 20991231                                    
    AND     UAPRGD < 1                                                              
    AND     UANOTT = 'E'                                                            
  ORDER BY  001 ASC, 008 ASC
```

**EDIT** I just noticed that UAFLWD is already included in the selection list without conversion in the sample SQL.

Comment: ok the issue is this. UAFLWD, when I use that field in the crystal report it gives more data output. I have to check fully, but some of them are bad data. We seem to allow users to enter bad dates. So I guess on the 400 that concat rejects bad data, e.g. a month over 12. what i need to do, is convert exactly what the query does on the 400 because that is the version of the truth

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell Crystal to treat the field as a string instead of a date so it doesn't bomb out?   Then you can have Crystal do some string->date conversion and checking.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use `cast()`:

```
SELECT                                                                              
  ALL       T01.UAUSRN,                                                             
            CAST(SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD),5,2) CONCAT SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD),7,2) CONCAT 
                 SUBSTR(DIGITS(UAFLWD),3,2) AS INTEGER
                ) AS FOLLOWUP,         
            (T01.UAENT#), T01.UASFX#, T02.ADENTN, T01.UANOTT, T01.UANOTL,  T02.ADLNM, T02.ADFNM,         
            T01.UAFLWD
```

Does this work to solve your problem?

Comment: this does not display anything for Followup.